# Get Window's Current Dimensions regardless of minimise/normal/maximise state

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to obtain a 'top level' HWND's dimensions. Ie, I want the *current* dimensions of the main HWND of the Firefox/Windows Explorer/etc. window.

`GetWindowRect()` wont work if the window is minimised. `GetWindowPlacement()` works for most cases (incl minimised) but it returns the windows' `SW_SHOWNORMAL` dimensions. So if I resize Windows Explorer down to 100 pixels by 100 pixels, maximise the window then call `GetWindowPlacement()` I will get the `SW_SHOWNORMAL` dimensions of 100x100. I want the maximised dimensions, ie, the *current* dimensions of the window.

Is there a one size fits all WinAPI function that will meet all my cases? Ie, tell me the *current* window dimensions when its visible (regardless if it is right now)? If not I guess I'm going to have to call `GetWindowPlacement()`, determine if the window is minimised. If true, use the normal dimensions otherwise call `GetWindowRect()`.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. You say you want the *current* dimensions, but if a window is minimized it's by definition not visible and is in a sense dimensionless.

Answer (score 2):

[GetWindowPlacement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633518(v=vs.85).aspx) will fill in a `WINDOWPLACEMENT` structure with the minimize and maximized positions as well as the normal position of the window.

It is crucial to note that the window positions returned are in workspace - not screen - co-ordinates, and so should be used in calls that accept workspace rather than screen co-ordinates.

Practically this means that if the user has positioned their taskbar across the top of the screen then "0,0" corresponds to the top left pixel below the taskbar.

In terms of getting the dimensions of the window when maximized, they would correspond to the dimensions of the monitor the window is maximized on. In that case there seems no single API call that can answer this question, as the question doesn't really make sense anymore: Why would you want the maximized size when maximized but the "normal" size when minimized? The user is just as likely to restore the window to a maximized or normal state.

Comment: [Additional Reading](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040707-00/?p=38523) Especially the warning about the window placement being in workspace coordinates _not_ screen coordinates.

Comment: And you beat me to the window/screen coordinate system warning.

Answer (score 0):

Use [IsIconic(hwnd)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to determine state of current window handle:

1. If normal/maximize state. Use [GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get its dimensions.
2. If minimize state, you should restore the window to get its dimensions like this ["3 & 5 - Restore/Minimize The Window"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20651/Capturing-Minimized-Window-A-Kid-s-Trick)

***Update***: Using *IsIconic()* instead of comparing rect(Left,Top) with -32000 to determine window handle state which are commented by @IInspectable and @Raymond Chen.

Comment: Where is the link to formal documentation for those comparisons against -32000?

Comment: Use `IsIconic` to detect a minimized window. The coordinates of minimized windows is not documented (and is not always less than -32000).

Comment: @IInspectable There is NOT formal documentation for -32000 when minimized. It is result which I google sample codes and output log.

Comment: @Raymond Chen I read msdn about IsIconic() and tried to use it. It work well. I will update my answer. thanks!